# Does yup or zod have a method to determine is schema is yup-schema or zod-schema?

Tags: validation, yup, zod

We have a project where we are using `yup` and now `zod` for validation, in parallel. We need a way to reliably distinguish one schema from another. Are there any methods in either of these to detect this? Something like: `yup.isYupSchema()` or `z.isZodSchema()`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is a schema that you have:

```
    const zodSchema = z.object({
      one: z.number(),
      two: z.object({
        three: z.number(),
        four: z.number(),
      }),
    });
```

Then you can check whether this is indeed a `zod` schema by running:

```
import { ZodObject } from 'zod';

zodSchema instanceof ZodObject
```